# Save entire UIWebView with objective-c?

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to save a UIWebView page for offline consultation, what could I use to solve the problem?

Comment: Save the data in NSUserDefaults and access it while you are offline

Comment: How save entire page in userdefault?

Comment: upload your code for displaying data in webview